# URL for cloudant on docker compose

Tags: docker-compose, cloudant

Using the docker compose, I'm trying to get my `app` to call the cloudant URL with the following values, but always get connection refused:

- http://admin:pass@0.0.0.0:8080
- http://admin:pass@cloudant:8080

But if I go to http://0.0.0.0:8080/dashboard.html, I can access the cloudant web console.

Here is my compose file (referencing the sample in  [Running Cloudant as docker container with docker compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42745469/running-cloudant-as-docker-container-with-docker-compose/42786311#42786311))

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  app:
    build: app/
    links:
    - cloudant
  cloudant:
    image: ibmcom/cloudant-developer:latest
    container_name: cloudant-testdb
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    expose:
      - "80"
    volumes:
      - cloudant:/srv
    mem_limit: 256M
    restart: always
    privileged: true
    network_mode: bridge
volumes:
    cloudant:
```

Comment: Have you tried to connect to the default port 5984?

Comment: Just tried.  No luck though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I got this to work:

1. Specify the hostname for the cloudant container in your docker-compose file like so:

   ```
   restart: always
   hostname: cloudant
   privileged: true
   ```
2. When communicating between containers you use the ports exposed by the services in the container, not the ports that are defined in the mapping. In this case you use the port exposed by Cloudant which is 80. So, your URL should look like this:

   http://admin:pass@cloudant
3. Set the `network_mode` value to `bridge` in the app container.

Here is a working example: https://github.com/markwatsonatx/tutorial-cloudant-nodejs-intro

Also, be sure to accept the license in Cloudant and initialize the database. You may need to restart docker-compose after doing so.

Comment: Thanks.  You're right. I should use the port 80 instead.  However, it's still not working.  When I tried to ping `cloudant` in my app container, it says unknown host.  Any ideas?

Comment: I updated my answer. I think you need to set the network_mode to bridge in the app container as well.

Comment: It's working!  Thanks so much @markwatsonatx.  I tried to use the `bridge` network before on the app but failed.  The key (at least for me) was to restart docker compose.